# Sort all columns of a pandas DataFrame independently using sort_values()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to sort all columns independently in descending or ascending order.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': [5, 2, 3, 6],
        'b': [7, 9, 1, 4],
        'c': [1, 5, 4, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
   a  b  c
0  5  7  1
1  2  9  5
2  3  1  4
3  6  4  2
```

When I use [sort_values()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for this it does not work as expected (to me) and only sorts one column:

```
foo = df.sort_values(by=['a', 'b', 'c'], ascending=[False, False, False])
   a  b  c
3  6  4  2
0  5  7  1
2  3  1  4
1  2  9  5
```

I can get the desired result if I use the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507040/sort-all-columns-of-a-dataframe) answer which applies a lambda function:

```
bar = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values)
print(bar)

   a  b  c
0  2  1  1
1  3  4  2
2  5  7  4
3  6  9  5
```

But this looks a bit heavy-handed to me.

What's actually happening in the [sort_values()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) example above and how can I sort all columns in my dataframe in a pandas-way without the lambda function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  2  1  1
1  3  4  2
2  5  7  4
3  6  9  5
```

EDIT:

Answer with descending order:

```
arr = df.values
arr.sort(axis=0)
arr = arr[::-1]
print (arr)
[[6 9 5]
 [5 7 4]
 [3 4 2]
 [2 1 1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  6  9  5
1  5  7  4
2  3  4  2
3  2  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would still prefer `df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values)` over it since it is shorter and does not require a numpy import.

Comment: Isn't there some standard pandas construct for this? ;)

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer there should be zero preference to avoid `numpy` when using pandas for the purpose of avoiding a `numpy` import.  That's because whey you import `pandas` you have already imported `numpy`.  In fact, you can use the `pandas` namespace to do exactly what jezrael did. `pd.DataFrame(pd.np.sort(df.values, axis=0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)`

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you for comment.

Comment: If use this solution, I think it is faster as apply solution in larger df. But both works very nice. In my opinion apply solution is better if not same dtypes of columns - e.g. one ic strings, another int, float. Because numpy works best with float, int arrays - same dtype.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help and explanation!

Comment: @ jezrael   How does one sort the values in the columns in descending order? this code performs an ascending form

Answer (score 5):

`sort_values` will sort the entire data frame by the columns order you pass to it. In your first example you are sorting the entire data frame with `['a', 'b', 'c']`. This will sort first by `'a'`, then by `'b'` and finally by `'c'`.

Notice how, after sorting by `a`, the rows maintain the same. This is the expected result.

Using `lambda` you are passing each column to it, this means `sort_values` will apply to a single column, and that's why this second approach sorts the columns as you would expect. In this case, the rows change.

If you don't want to use `lambda` nor `numpy` you can get around using this:

```
pd.DataFrame({x: df[x].sort_values().values for x in df.columns.values})
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  2  1  1
1  3  4  2
2  5  7  4
3  6  9  5
```

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer edited with new way of sorting `df` without using `lambda` nor `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help and explanation!