# Pandas DataFrame Sort every Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is a nice way of sorting every column alphabetically in a pandas DataFrame?

Example:

```
df = DataFrame({'A':['Bob','Rob','Dob'],'B':['Dob','Bob','Rob'],'C':['Rob','Bob','Dob']})

df

     A   B   C
0   Bob Dob Rob
1   Rob Bob Bob
2   Dob Rob Dob
```

I want:

```
     A   B   C
0   Bob Bob Bob
1   Dob Dob Dob
2   Rob Rob Rob
```

Comment: @miradulo Really, the top voted answer there uses apply + sort_values... for shame

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This is another with your answer at the top: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280322/sort-all-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-independently-using-sort-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.sort` along the first axis.

```
df[:] = np.sort(df, axis=0)
```

Or, even simpler,

```
df.values.sort(axis=0)
```

```
df
     A    B    C
0  Bob  Bob  Bob
1  Dob  Dob  Dob
2  Rob  Rob  Rob
```