# Sort columns in Pivot table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

folks. I've been through all the questions related to sorting columns with pivot tables but couldn't find something just as I needed. I have a dataframe of this kind:

```
        Date  Moisture     Accum  Year  DayOfYear
0 2000-01-01  0.408640  0.408640  2000          1
1 2000-01-02  0.433425  0.842065  2000          2
2 2000-01-03  0.429745  1.271810  2000          3
3 2000-01-04  0.427589  1.699399  2000          4
4 2000-01-05  0.428700  2.128098  2000          5
```

And I created a Pivot table from it and calculated another column from the existing data:

```
mean1 = pd.pivot_table(c1, index = 'DayOfYear', columns = 'Year', values = 'Moisture')
mean1['Mean'] = mean1.mean(axis = 1)
```

I obtained something like this:

```
Year           2000      2001      2002  ...      2018      2019      Mean
DayOfYear                                ...                              
1          0.408640  0.433016  0.420326  ...  0.423164  0.328385  0.401896
2          0.433425  0.423607  0.414502  ...  0.419587  0.322804  0.398434
3          0.429745  0.418132  0.404171  ...  0.417384  0.318795  0.396913
4          0.427589  0.407190  0.394478  ...  0.420361  0.316989  0.398425
5          0.428700  0.401072  0.386432  ...  0.417026  0.313664  0.396777
```

I want to sort the values for each year, but I haven't been able to make it happen. I've tried this:

```
mean1 = mean1.sort_values('2000', ascending = True, axis = 0)
```

But I get `KeyError: '2000'`. I also tried sorting by the value I made the pivot table from ('Moisture'), as responses to other questions recommended, but it keeps showing a similar error.
If I try to sort the values from the 'Mean' column I do get the sorted column, but it can't be done (apparently) for the year columns (e.g. '2000').
What am I missing?

Comment: is it the string `'2000'` or the int `2000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort every column independently, you may try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280322/sort-all-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-independently-using-sort-values), which is the same as:

```
import numpy as np

mean2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(mean1.values, axis=0), index=mean1.index, columns=mean1.columns)
```

Which will give you a DataFrame with each column sorted individually.

```
Year           2000      2001      2002      2018      2019      Mean
DayOfYear                                                            
1          0.408640  0.401072  0.386432  0.417026  0.313664  0.389379
2          0.427589  0.407190  0.394478  0.417384  0.316989  0.393321
3          0.428700  0.418132  0.404171  0.419587  0.318795  0.397645
4          0.429745  0.423607  0.414502  0.420361  0.322804  0.402706
5          0.433425  0.433016  0.420326  0.423164  0.328385  0.402785
```

But now the index doesn't make sense at all, since all cells were reordered. So maybe you'll want to reindex it.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Year* column in your source DataFrame is most likely of *int* type,
so the respective column in the pivot table has also "integer" (not
"string") name (run `mean1.info()` to check column types).

So the first, mandatory correction is to change the first parameter
to **integer** *2000*.

Two another correction are in my opinion advisable, but not required:
Default values of *ascending* and *axis* parameters are *True* and *0*,
respectively, so if you want to keep your code shorter, you can omit them.

So replace the offending line with:

```
mean1 = mean1.sort_values(2000)
```