# Sorting correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, correlation

I want to convert the correlation matrix to the "pandas" table, sorted from the largest value to the smallest, as in the image. How can I do it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,15,size=(20, 6)), columns=["Ply_1","Ply_2","Ply_3","Ply_4","Ply_5","Ply_6"])
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=20, freq='D')
df = df.set_index(['date'])
cor=df.corr()
print(cor)
```

[Out image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cbwm.jpg)

Comment: You [shouldn't use an image here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).
What you have provided in your image can be represented as text formatted as code.
You can [edit] your post to make changes.

Comment: In pandas there is usually one row index the whole row (which is same). Do you also need the information about the order of new rows for each column? Then how do you imagine it?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cbwm.jpg          
I want to get an output like this

Comment: so do you want 12 columns in your new dataframe?

Comment: [Sort all columns of a pandas DataFrame independently using sort_values()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43280322/14627505)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Vladimir. For each order, I want to see the values ​​and the label they belong to, also to the left.     https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS9QG.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much, Vladimir. You answered my question with great skill. I'm grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
pd.concat([cor[col_name].sort_values(ascending=False)
                        .rename_axis(col_name.replace('Ply', 'index'))
                        .reset_index() 
           for col_name in cor], 
          axis=1)
```

#### Explanation:

- `pd.concat([df_1, ..., df_6], axis=1)` concatenates 6 dataframes (each one will be already sorted and will have 2 columns: ‘index_i’ and ‘Ply_i’).
- `[cor[col_name] for col_name in cor]` would create a list of 6 Series, where each Series is the next column of `cor`.
- `ser.sort_values(ascending=False)` sorts values of a Series `ser` in the descending order (indices also move - together with their values).
- `col_name.replace('Ply', 'index')` creates a new string from a string `col_name` by replacing 'Ply' with 'index'.
- `ser.rename_axis(name).reset_index()` renames the index axis, and extracts the index (with its name) as a new column, converting a Series into a DataFrame. The new index of this dataframe is the default range index (from 0 to 6).

#### Result:

(with my randomly generated numbers)

|  | index_1 | Ply_1 | index_2 | Ply_2 | index_3 | Ply_3 | index_4 | Ply_4 | index_5 | Ply_5 | index_6 | Ply_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ply_1 | 1 | Ply_2 | 1 | Ply_3 | 1 | Ply_4 | 1 | Ply_5 | 1 | Ply_6 | 1 |
| 1 | Ply_2 | 0.387854 | Ply_1 | 0.387854 | Ply_1 | 0.258825 | Ply_1 | 0.337613 | Ply_4 | 0.0618012 | Ply_1 | 0.058282 |
| 2 | Ply_4 | 0.337613 | Ply_4 | 0.293496 | Ply_4 | 0.0552454 | Ply_2 | 0.293496 | Ply_2 | 0.060881 | Ply_3 | -0.207621 |
| 3 | Ply_3 | 0.258825 | Ply_5 | 0.060881 | Ply_2 | -0.0900126 | Ply_5 | 0.0618012 | Ply_3 | -0.110885 | Ply_2 | -0.22012 |
| 4 | Ply_6 | 0.058282 | Ply_3 | -0.0900126 | Ply_5 | -0.110885 | Ply_3 | 0.0552454 | Ply_1 | -0.390893 | Ply_4 | -0.291842 |
| 5 | Ply_5 | -0.390893 | Ply_6 | -0.22012 | Ply_6 | -0.207621 | Ply_6 | -0.291842 | Ply_6 | -0.394074 | Ply_5 | -0.394074 |