# Sort every column of a dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working in Spark & Scala and have a dataframe with several hundred columns. I would like to sort the dataframe by every column. Is there anyway to do this in Scala/Spark?

I have tried:

```
val sortedDf = actualDF.sort(actualDF.columns)
```

but `.sort` does not support `Array[String]` input.

This question has been asked before: [Sort all columns of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507040/sort-all-columns-of-a-dataframe) but there is no Scala answer

Comment: Try `actualDF.sort(actualDF.columns.map(col): _*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @blackbishop for the answer to this:

```
val dfSortedByAllItsColumns = actualDF.sort(actualDF.columns.map(col): _*)
```

Comment: Won't work if you have a column of type Map