# Sorting a multindex data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, tuples, multi-index

I am trying to work on a requirement where I want to sort values in a multiindex dataframe, here is my below code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s={'Fruits':['Apple','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango'],'month':[2014,2015,2016,2017],'Weight':[2,4,1,7],'Quant':[5,2,3,9]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
df=pd.pivot_table(p,index='Fruits',columns='month',values=['Weight','Quant'],aggfunc=np.sum)
df=df.fillna(0)
```

The dataframe looks like this-

[image]

I am trying to sort values based on Quant, so every column ie 2014-2017,present in Quant, its values needs to be arranged in an ascending order.

I am trying the below code, but getting an error, how would I rectify this-

```
df.sort_values(by='Quant')

ValueError: The column label 'Quant' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

Comment: But if you arrange the values in increasing order, then the values won't match the fruit name on that line?

Comment: Could you please show what the expected resulting dataframe would be on your example?

Comment: Does this related question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507040/sort-all-columns-of-a-dataframe

Comment: Yes to some extent, thanks Stef, appreciate it!